# ReSharper - Apply [CanBeNull] attribute to stuff in external assemblies?

Tags: null, resharper, nullreferenceexception

Using ReSharper, one may denote that something may be null, or will never be null, using `[CanBeNull]` or `[NotNull]` respectively. However, it only seems possible to have the benefits of this null analysis on your own code, where you yourself can add the attribute.

Is there a way to mark methods, properties, fields, etc. from *other* assemblies (where one does not have the source) as possibly being null, or never being null, in a similar fashion?

For example, one might want to mark Unity's `GetComponent()` method with `[CanBeNull]`, so that ReSharper can help you identify areas where `NullReferenceException`s may be thrown. However, seeing as how we don't have Unity's source code, we cannot add it ourselves.

Is there another way to do this? Perhaps ReSharper has some sort of internal file where you can manually add references to assembly members that are `[NotNull]` or `[CanBeNull]` without using attributes directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html?

Yes, they already have this feature. I should have googled it harder. :)